# Windows Update gives 0x80070643 error on fresh Windows 10 install

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v22h2

I just did a clean install of Windows 10 22H2 onto a freshly wiped hard disk. (If it matters, I installed from a USB drive that I prepared with the Windows 10 Media Creation Tool yesterday.) When it tried to install updates, most of them succeeded, but one failed: [2023-10 Update for Windows 10 Version 22H2 for x64-based Systems (KB5001716)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5001716-update-for-windows-update-service-components-fb9dd3d3-d702-4f8a-af10-b9551cfa6e13) failed to install with error code 0x80070643.

Here's the part of the `Get-WindowsUpdateLog` output from when this update tries and fails (with timestamps removed to get the post size under the limit):

```
6812  9384  DownloadManager * START * Begin Downloading Updates [CallerId = MoUpdateOrchestrator] [Call ID = {0313BB53-6F05-4B47-B1A0-324C32992836}]
6812  9384  DownloadManager Priority = 2, NetworkCostPolicy = 0, Interactive = 1, Download on Battery = 1, Bypass Regulation = 1, Owner is system = 1, Proxy session id = 1, ServiceId = 9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77.
6812  9384  DownloadManager Updates to download = 1
6812  9384  Agent             Title = 2023-10 Update for Windows 10 Version 22H2 for x64-based Systems (KB5001716)
6812  9384  Agent             UpdateId = B3FF3645-9E26-432A-9821-D1033FAF5D93.200
6812  9384  Agent               Bundles 1 updates:
6812  9384  Agent                 974E8301-34D8-4BFF-89CA-61488711440A.200
6812  9384  DownloadManager Regulation: {9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77} - Loaded sequence number 65535 for regulation category PerUpdate.
6812  9384  DownloadManager Regulation: {9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77} - Loaded sequence number 65535 for regulation category Low.
6812  9384  DownloadManager Regulation: {9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77} - Loaded sequence number 65535 for regulation category Normal.
6812  9384  DownloadManager Regulation: {9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77} - Loaded sequence number 65535 for regulation category High.
6812  9384  SLS             Get response for service 9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77 - forceExpire[False] asyncRefreshOnExpiry[False]
6812  9384  SLS             path used for cache lookup: /SLS/{9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77}/x64/10.0.19045.4046/0?CH=910&L=en-US&P=&PT=0x65&WUA=10.0.19041.3996&MK=Hewlett-Packard&MD=HP+Pavilion+17+Notebook+PC
6812  9384  DownloadManager Queueing update 974E8301-34D8-4BFF-89CA-61488711440A.200 for download handler request generation.
6812  9384  Agent           Effective power state: AC; IsOnAC: Yes.
6812  9384  IdleTimer       WU operation (DL.MoUpdateOrchestrator, operation # 80) stopped; does use network; is not at background priority
6812  9384  Agent           Released network PDC reference for callId {0313BB53-6F05-4B47-B1A0-324C32992836}; ActivationID: 80
6812  9384  IdleTimer       WU operation (DL.MoUpdateOrchestrator) started; operation # 81; does use network; is not at background priority
6812  9384  Agent           Obtained a network PDC reference for callID {0313BB53-6F05-4B47-B1A0-324C32992836} with No-Progress-Timeout set to 4294967295; ActivationID: 81.
6812  9384  DownloadManager * END * Begin Downloading Updates [CallerId = MoUpdateOrchestrator] [Call ID = {0313BB53-6F05-4B47-B1A0-324C32992836}] [hr = 0x00000000]
5700  9888  ComApi          * START *   Federated Download ClientId = MoUpdateOrchestrator (cV = 6BW+6lnxVkC1GtQU.2.0)
5700  7408  ComApi          Federated Download: Starting download for 1 service(s) (cV = 6BW+6lnxVkC1GtQU.2.0)
5700  7408  ComApi          * START *   Download ClientId = MoUpdateOrchestrator 
5700  7408  ComApi          Flags: 0X1100C; Download priority: 2; Network Cost Policy: 0
5700  7408  ComApi          Updates in request: 1
5700  7408  ComApi          ServiceID = {9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77} Windows Update
6812  9152  Agent           WU client calls back to download call {0313BB53-6F05-4B47-B1A0-324C32992836} with code Call progress and error 0
6812  9388  SLS             Get response for service 9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77 - forceExpire[False] asyncRefreshOnExpiry[False]
6812  9388  SLS             path used for cache lookup: /SLS/{9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77}/x64/10.0.19045.4046/0?CH=910&L=en-US&P=&PT=0x65&WUA=10.0.19041.3996&MK=Hewlett-Packard&MD=HP+Pavilion+17+Notebook+PC
6812  9388  DownloadManager Generating download request for update 974E8301-34D8-4BFF-89CA-61488711440A.200.
6812  9384  Agent           Effective power state: AC; IsOnAC: Yes.
6812  9384  IdleTimer       WU operation (DL.MoUpdateOrchestrator) started; operation # 86; does use network; is not at background priority
6812  9384  Agent           Obtained a network PDC reference for callID {6FAD24C3-A3E5-4E37-B26C-66FE8740CF22} with No-Progress-Timeout set to 4294967295; ActivationID: 86.
5700  7408  ComApi          *QUEUED* Download ClientId = MoUpdateOrchestrator
6812  9388  DownloadManager Calling into handler 0x3 to generate download request for update 974E8301-34D8-4BFF-89CA-61488711440A.200.
6812  9388  Handler         MSP download: file Windows10.0-KB5001716-x64.cab already exists in sandbox directory (C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download\9318a56b6e92b73e26bc1e9cca0ec4e6)
6812  9384  DownloadManager * START * Begin Downloading Updates [CallerId = MoUpdateOrchestrator] [Call ID = {6FAD24C3-A3E5-4E37-B26C-66FE8740CF22}]
6812  9384  DownloadManager Priority = 2, NetworkCostPolicy = 0, Interactive = 1, Download on Battery = 1, Bypass Regulation = 1, Owner is system = 1, Proxy session id = 1, ServiceId = 9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77.
6812  9384  DownloadManager Updates to download = 1
6812  9384  Agent             Title = Security Intelligence Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Version 1.407.10.0) - Current Channel (Broad)
6812  9384  Agent             UpdateId = E3348E31-0498-48A2-BF27-63062DAF29F4.200
6812  9384  Agent               Bundles 1 updates:
6812  9384  Agent                 A5600AE4-5E8F-400E-B48C-93BC159B211E.200
6812  9384  DownloadManager No locked revisions found for update E3348E31-0498-48A2-BF27-63062DAF29F4.200 (SessionData = (null)); locking the user-specified revision.
6812  9384  DownloadManager No locked revisions found for update A5600AE4-5E8F-400E-B48C-93BC159B211E.200 (SessionData = (null)); locking the user-specified revision.
6812  9388  Handler         MSP Download: file C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download\9318a56b6e92b73e26bc1e9cca0ec4e6\Windows10.0-KB5001716-x64.cab passed cert/hash validation.
6812  9384  SLS             Get response for service 9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77 - forceExpire[False] asyncRefreshOnExpiry[False]
6812  9384  SLS             path used for cache lookup: /SLS/{9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77}/x64/10.0.19045.4046/0?CH=910&L=en-US&P=&PT=0x65&WUA=10.0.19041.3996&MK=Hewlett-Packard&MD=HP+Pavilion+17+Notebook+PC
6812  9384  DownloadManager The update's sandbox is in use.  Will download when it is no longer busy.
6812  9384  SLS             Get response for service 9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77 - forceExpire[False] asyncRefreshOnExpiry[False]
6812  9384  SLS             path used for cache lookup: /SLS/{9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77}/x64/10.0.19045.4046/0?CH=910&L=en-US&P=&PT=0x65&WUA=10.0.19041.3996&MK=Hewlett-Packard&MD=HP+Pavilion+17+Notebook+PC
6812  9384  DownloadManager DO job initialized: JobId = {4E5ED6CC-69D2-4EBA-B943-B5E96E2E394E}
6812  9384  DownloadManager Downloading from http://au.download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/defu/2024/03/am_delta_patch_1.407.8.0_7f8d1376a3e4226bed35b0d59ca694fe6a7977f0.exe to C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download\5e9bb8bb79814e2cfc4047c7e5727cc9\7f8d1376a3e4226bed35b0d59ca694fe6a7977f0 (full file)
6812  9384  DownloadManager Created download job 4E5ED6CC-69D2-4EBA-B943-B5E96E2E394E; streaming data: No.
6812  9384  DownloadManager New download job {4E5ED6CC-69D2-4EBA-B943-B5E96E2E394E} for UpdateId A5600AE4-5E8F-400E-B48C-93BC159B211E.200
6812  9384  SLS             Get response for service 9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77 - forceExpire[False] asyncRefreshOnExpiry[False]
6812  9384  SLS             path used for cache lookup: /SLS/{9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77}/x64/10.0.19045.4046/0?CH=910&L=en-US&P=&PT=0x65&WUA=10.0.19041.3996&MK=Hewlett-Packard&MD=HP+Pavilion+17+Notebook+PC
6812  9384  DownloadManager Update the URLs for DO Job 4E5ED6CC-69D2-4EBA-B943-B5E96E2E394E - Update A5600AE4-5E8F-400E-B48C-93BC159B211E.200
6812  9384  DownloadManager 0 of 1 files' URLs are updated.
6812  9384  DownloadManager Download job 4E5ED6CC-69D2-4EBA-B943-B5E96E2E394E resumed.
6812  9384  Agent           Effective power state: AC; IsOnAC: Yes.
6812  9384  IdleTimer       WU operation (DL.MoUpdateOrchestrator, operation # 86) stopped; does use network; is not at background priority
6812  9384  Agent           Released network PDC reference for callId {6FAD24C3-A3E5-4E37-B26C-66FE8740CF22}; ActivationID: 86
6812  9384  IdleTimer       WU operation (DL.MoUpdateOrchestrator) started; operation # 87; does use network; is not at background priority
6812  9384  Agent           Obtained a network PDC reference for callID {6FAD24C3-A3E5-4E37-B26C-66FE8740CF22} with No-Progress-Timeout set to 4294967295; ActivationID: 87.
6812  9152  Agent           WU client calls back to download call {6FAD24C3-A3E5-4E37-B26C-66FE8740CF22} with code Call progress and error 0
6812  9384  DownloadManager * END * Begin Downloading Updates [CallerId = MoUpdateOrchestrator] [Call ID = {6FAD24C3-A3E5-4E37-B26C-66FE8740CF22}] [hr = 0x00000000]
6812  9384  SLS             Get response for service 9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77 - forceExpire[False] asyncRefreshOnExpiry[False]
6812  9384  SLS             path used for cache lookup: /SLS/{9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77}/x64/10.0.19045.4046/0?CH=910&L=en-US&P=&PT=0x65&WUA=10.0.19041.3996&MK=Hewlett-Packard&MD=HP+Pavilion+17+Notebook+PC
6812  9384  DownloadManager Avoiding download as update is already marked complete.
6812  9384  DownloadManager All files for update 974E8301-34D8-4BFF-89CA-61488711440A.200 were already downloaded and are valid.
6812  9384  DownloadManager Update 0 in call 4 was already downloaded (totalBytes=0). Notifying call.
6812  9384  DownloadManager * END * Download Call Complete. Call 4 for caller MoUpdateOrchestrator has completed; signaling completion.
6812  9384  Agent           Effective power state: AC; IsOnAC: Yes.
6812  9384  IdleTimer       WU operation (DL.MoUpdateOrchestrator, operation # 81) stopped; does use network; is not at background priority
6812  9384  Agent           Released network PDC reference for callId {0313BB53-6F05-4B47-B1A0-324C32992836}; ActivationID: 81
5700  9896  ComApi          *RESUMED* Download ClientId = MoUpdateOrchestrator
5700  9896  ComApi          Download call complete (succeeded = 1, succeeded with errors = 0, failed = 0, cancelled = 0, unaccounted = 0)
5700  9896  ComApi          * END *   Download ClientId = MoUpdateOrchestrator
6812  9152  Agent           WU client calls back to download call {0313BB53-6F05-4B47-B1A0-324C32992836} with code Call complete and error 0
5700  7464  ComApi          Download call complete (succeeded = 1, succeeded with errors = 0, failed = 0, cancelled = 0, unaccounted = 0)
5700  7464  ComApi          * END *   All federated downloads have completed. ClientId = MoUpdateOrchestrator (cV = 6BW+6lnxVkC1GtQU.1.1)
5700  8592  ComApi          * START *   GetAttributeInt   Attribute name = IsUpgradeRepair
6812  9384  SLS             Get response for service 9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77 - forceExpire[False] asyncRefreshOnExpiry[False]
6812  9384  SLS             path used for cache lookup: /SLS/{9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77}/x64/10.0.19045.4046/0?CH=910&L=en-US&P=&PT=0x65&WUA=10.0.19041.3996&MK=Hewlett-Packard&MD=HP+Pavilion+17+Notebook+PC
6812  9384  SLS             Get response for service 9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77 - forceExpire[False] asyncRefreshOnExpiry[False]
6812  9384  SLS             path used for cache lookup: /SLS/{9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77}/x64/10.0.19045.4046/0?CH=910&L=en-US&P=&PT=0x65&WUA=10.0.19041.3996&MK=Hewlett-Packard&MD=HP+Pavilion+17+Notebook+PC
6812  9384  DownloadManager Update the URLs for DO Job 4E5ED6CC-69D2-4EBA-B943-B5E96E2E394E - Update A5600AE4-5E8F-400E-B48C-93BC159B211E.200
6812  9384  DownloadManager 0 of 1 files' URLs are updated.
6812  9384  DownloadManager Download job 4E5ED6CC-69D2-4EBA-B943-B5E96E2E394E resumed.
5700  8592  ComApi          * END *   GetAttributeInt   Attribute value = [0]
5700  8592  ComApi          Reloading CUpdate B3FF3645-9E26-432A-9821-D1033FAF5D93.200 from datastore...
6812  9384  SLS             Get response for service 9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77 - forceExpire[False] asyncRefreshOnExpiry[False]
6812  9384  SLS             path used for cache lookup: /SLS/{9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77}/x64/10.0.19045.4046/0?CH=910&L=en-US&P=&PT=0x65&WUA=10.0.19041.3996&MK=Hewlett-Packard&MD=HP+Pavilion+17+Notebook+PC
5700  8592  ComApi          Deserializing update from serialized BSTR.
5700  8592  ComApi          Byte length of the input buffer for deserialization: 15430
5700  8592  ComApi          Deserializing update from serialized BSTR.
5700  8592  ComApi          Deserialized installable update 2023-10 Update for Windows 10 Version 22H2 for x64-based Systems (KB5001716), UpdateID = {B3FF3645-9E26-432A-9821-D1033FAF5D93.200}, CallbackInfo cookie length = 0
5700  8592  ComApi          Reload successful, UpdateID =  B3FF3645-9E26-432A-9821-D1033FAF5D93.200, CallbackInfo cookie length = 0, Current deployment action = 1, New deployment action = 1
6812  9384  DownloadManager Update the URLs for DO Job 4E5ED6CC-69D2-4EBA-B943-B5E96E2E394E - Update A5600AE4-5E8F-400E-B48C-93BC159B211E.200
5700  8592  ComApi          Serializing CUpdate B3FF3645-9E26-432A-9821-D1033FAF5D93.200
6812  9384  DownloadManager 0 of 1 files' URLs are updated.
5700  8592  ComApi          Update serialization complete. BSTR byte length = 15430, CallbackInfo cookie length = 0
6812  9384  DownloadManager Download job 4E5ED6CC-69D2-4EBA-B943-B5E96E2E394E resumed.
5700  9884  ComApi          Caller requested deployment provider mode is 2
5700  9884  ComApi          Using caller specified deployment provider mode 2
5700  9884  ComApi          * START *   Federated Install   ClientId = MoUpdateOrchestrator (cV: 6BW+6lnxVkC1GtQU.3.0)
5700  3116  ComApi          * START *   Install ClientId = MoUpdateOrchestrator, Flags: 0X12100 (cV: 6BW+6lnxVkC1GtQU.3.0.0)
5700  3116  ComApi          Allow source prompts: Yes; Forced: No; Force quiet: No; Attempt close apps if necessary: No
5700  3116  ComApi          Updates in request: 1
5700  3116  ComApi          ServiceID = {9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77} Windows Update
6812  9288  Agent           Validating updates before Install
6812  2324  Agent           Effective power state: AC; IsOnAC: Yes.
6812  2324  IdleTimer       WU operation (DL.MoUpdateOrchestrator, operation # 87) stopped; does use network; is not at background priority
6812  2324  Agent           Released network PDC reference for callId {6FAD24C3-A3E5-4E37-B26C-66FE8740CF22}; ActivationID: 87
6812  2324  IdleTimer       WU operation (DL.MoUpdateOrchestrator) started; operation # 98; does use network; is not at background priority
6812  2324  Agent           Obtained a network PDC reference for callID {6FAD24C3-A3E5-4E37-B26C-66FE8740CF22} with No-Progress-Timeout set to 4294967295; ActivationID: 98.
6812  9152  Agent           WU client calls back to download call {6FAD24C3-A3E5-4E37-B26C-66FE8740CF22} with code Call progress and error 0
6812  9288  Agent           Pre-install check complete
5700  3116  UDP             BeginUpdateDeployment invoked for Installing the 1 updates; Caller id = MoUpdateOrchestrator
5700  3116  UDP             Installing update: B3FF3645-9E26-432A-9821-D1033FAF5D93.200
5700  3116  UDP             Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : Created successfully.
5700  3116  WIL             *FAILED* [8024801E] file = onecore\enduser\windowsupdate\client\engine\updatedeploymentprovider\lib\dpupdatehelper.cpp, line = 632
5700  3116  WIL             *FAILED* [8024801E] file = onecore\enduser\windowsupdate\client\engine\updatedeploymentprovider\lib\dpupdatehelper.cpp, line = 632
5700  3116  WIL             *FAILED* [8024801E] file = onecore\enduser\windowsupdate\client\engine\updatedeploymentprovider\lib\dpupdatehelper.cpp, line = 632
5700  3116  WIL             *FAILED* [8024801E] file = onecore\enduser\windowsupdate\client\engine\updatedeploymentprovider\lib\dpupdatehelper.cpp, line = 632
5700  3116  UDP             Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : Deploy updates for Installing created successfully.
5700  3116  UDP             Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : Created DeploymentWorker(0) successfully.
5700  3116  UDP             Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : Created CallbackWorker(0) successfully.
5700  3116  UDP             Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : Initialized successfully.
5700  3116  ComApi          WU client created update deployment job BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6.
5700  3116  UDP             Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : Resume request received. Job status = Not Processed
5700  3116  UDP             Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : Resume request processing complete. Job Status = Ongoing
5700  3116  UDP             Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : End invoked for deployment job. Job status = Ongoing
5700  3748  UDP             Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : Beginning Installing of updates, CallerId = MoUpdateOrchestrator.
5700  3748  UDP               Title = 2023-10 Update for Windows 10 Version 22H2 for x64-based Systems (KB5001716)
5700  3748  UDP               UpdateId = B3FF3645-9E26-432A-9821-D1033FAF5D93.200
5700  3748  UDP                 Bundles 1 updates:
5700  3748  UDP                   974E8301-34D8-4BFF-89CA-61488711440A.200
5700  3748  UDP             Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : Mutex for Deployment job is created.  Mutex = b3c75dc1-155f-4be4-b015-3f1a91758e52
5700  3748  UDP             Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : Update B3FF3645-9E26-432A-9821-D1033FAF5D93.200 started delegate invoked.
5700  3748  UDP             Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : Installing starting for update B3FF3645-9E26-432A-9821-D1033FAF5D93.200, deployable update count = 1
5700  3748  Handler         Registering JIT COM server with CLSID {9A86CB76-1093-4DB2-A4BB-EA26791B48B2} and APPID {8E6697D7-C20F-45DE-9464-10F63D5A348A}
5700  3748  Handler         Successfully registered JIT COM server
5700  3748  Handler         Switching to UpdateDeploymentProvider.dll
4028  4040  Handler         UH: CoCreateInstance of remote handler succeeded with CLSID 9a86cb76-1093-4db2-a4bb-ea26791b48b2
4028  4040  Handler         UH: RegisterRemoteHandlerServer suceedded
6812  2324  DownloadManager Preparing update for install, updateId = 974E8301-34D8-4BFF-89CA-61488711440A.200.
5700  3748  UDP             Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : Update B3FF3645-9E26-432A-9821-D1033FAF5D93.200 deployment data prepared successfully.
4028  4116  Handler         * START *   MSI Install
4028  4116  Handler         Updates to Install = 1
4028  4116  Handler         MSI update {974E8301-34D8-4BFF-89CA-61488711440A}.200 using source image from 1 CABs.
4028  4116  Handler         Batch installing 1 updates
4028  4116  Handler         List of MSPs in transaction:
4028  4116  Handler         List of Transforms in transaction:
4028  4116  Handler         MSI final command line:  ALLUSERS=1 MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL=Disable REBOOT=REALLYSUPPRESS
4028  4116  Handler         MSP Error List:
4028  4116  Handler           No messages in the MSP error list.
4028  4116  Handler         MSI transaction completed. MSI: 0x80070643, Handler: 0x8024200b, Source: No, Reboot: 0
4028  4116  Handler         Removing sandbox from MSI source list failed. 0x80070645
4028  4116  Handler         Updating status for update 0.
4028  4116  Handler         First failure for update {974E8301-34D8-4BFF-89CA-61488711440A.200}, transaction error = 0x8024200b, MSI result = 0x80070643, MSI action = LaunchConditions
4028  4116  Handler         Sending completion notification for update 0 ({974E8301-34D8-4BFF-89CA-61488711440A}.200).
5700  8592  UDP             Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : Update B3FF3645-9E26-432A-9821-D1033FAF5D93.200 failure delegate invoked.
4028  4116  Handler         Stopping on first error due to FailOptTerminate.
4028  4116  Handler         Operation failed at update 0, Exit code = 0x8024200B
4028  4116  Handler         * END *   MSI Install
5700  5112  UDP             Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : NotifyClient (5112)(0) called for update id B3FF3645-9E26-432A-9821-D1033FAF5D93, code = Update failed, percent complete = 100
6812  2324  Agent           LogHistory called. idUpdate={B3FF3645-9E26-432A-9821-D1033FAF5D93}.200, resultMapped=80070643, resultUnMapped=80070643
6812  2324  Agent           WU client logged Install deloyment history, caller = MoUpdateOrchestrator, update B3FF3645-9E26-432A-9821-D1033FAF5D93.200, classification CD5FFD1E-E932-4E3A-BF74-18BF0B1BBD83
5700  5112  WIL             *FAILED* [80070002] file = onecore\enduser\windowsupdate\client\comapi\deploymentjobhost.cpp, line = 1468
5700  5112  WIL             *FAILED* [80070002] file = onecore\enduser\windowsupdate\client\comapi\deploymentjobhost.cpp, line = 1075
5700  5112  ComApi          Deployment callback complete for UpdateID = b3ff3645-9e26-432a-9821-d1033faf5d93, callback code = 8, CallbackInfo cookie length = 0
5700  3748  WIL             *FAILED* [80070002] file = onecore\enduser\windowsupdate\client\comapi\deploymentjobhost.cpp, line = 1468
5700  3748  WIL             *FAILED* [80070002] file = onecore\enduser\windowsupdate\client\comapi\deploymentjobhost.cpp, line = 1147
5700  3748  UDP             *FAILED* [80070643] Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : Installing for Top level update id B3FF3645-9E26-432A-9821-D1033FAF5D93.200, bundled update id 974E8301-34D8-4BFF-89CA-61488711440A.200 [CUpdateDeploymentJob::DeploySingleUpdateInternal:2800]
5700  3748  UDP             *FAILED* [8024200B] Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : Installing for Top level update id B3FF3645-9E26-432A-9821-D1033FAF5D93.200, bundled update id 974E8301-34D8-4BFF-89CA-61488711440A.200 [CUpdateDeploymentJob::DeploySingleUpdateInternal:2817]
5700  3748  WIL             *FAILED* [8024200B] file = onecore\enduser\windowsupdate\client\engine\updatedeploymentprovider\lib\updatedeploymentjob.cpp, line = 2819
5700  3748  UDP             Mutex will be closed.  index = 0, HANDLE = 0x00000324
5700  3748  UDP             Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : Method failed for update B3FF3645-9E26-432A-9821-D1033FAF5D93.200, hrDeploy = 0x8024200b
5700  3748  UDP             Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : Update B3FF3645-9E26-432A-9821-D1033FAF5D93.200 failure delegate invoked.
5700  3748  UDP             Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : Job complete delegate invoked.
4028  4040  Handler         *FAILED* [800700B7] Handler process got unexpected result: 0, exiting
5700  3748  UDP             Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : Ending Installing updates, CallerId = MoUpdateOrchestrator, Exit code = 0x00000000
5700  7828  UDP             Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : NotifyClient (7828)(0) called with Deployment callback code = Job complete, reboot status = no reboot
5700  7828  ComApi           Install ClientId = MoUpdateOrchestrator
5700  7828  ComApi          Install call complete (succeeded = 0, succeeded with errors = 0, failed = 1, cancelled = 0, unaccounted = 0
5700  7828  ComApi          Reboot required = False
5700  7828  ComApi          Call error code = 0x80240022
5700  7828  ComApi          * END *   Install ClientId = MoUpdateOrchestrator
5700  3824  UDP             Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : WaitForEnd invoked for deployment job. Beginning the wait now!
5700  3824  UDP             Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : WaitForEnd for deployment job completed. Job state = Complete
5700  3824  UDP             Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : CallbackWorker returning successfully.
5700  3116  UDP             Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : WaitForEnd invoked for deployment job. Beginning the wait now!
5700  3116  UDP             Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : WaitForEnd for deployment job completed. Job state = Complete
5700  3116  ComApi          WU client update deployment job BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 end wait complete.
5700  3116  UDP             Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : Per-job deployment completed = Yes"
5700  3116  UDP             Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : EndUpdateDeployment invoked for job. Job complete = Yes, erase Job = True
5700  3116  ComApi          WU client EndUpdateDeployment for deployment job BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 complete.
5700  3116  ComApi          WU client update deployment job BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 deployment result. hr = 0x00000000
5700  3116  UDP             Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : FinalRelease for deployment job.
5700  3116  UDP             Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : WaitForEnd invoked for deployment job. Beginning the wait now!
5700  3116  UDP             Deployment job Id BE02BA51-5F28-4B62-BE6E-B0C4F06DD9B6 : WaitForEnd for deployment job completed. Job state = Complete
5700  3116  ComApi          *QUEUED* Updates to Install = 1
5700  3116  ComApi          Install ClientId = MoUpdateOrchestrator (cV: 6BW+6lnxVkC1GtQU.3.0.0)
5700  3116  ComApi          Install call complete (succeeded = 0, succeeded with errors = 0, failed = 1, cancelled = 0, unaccounted = 0
5700  3116  ComApi          * END *   All federated installs have completed. ClientId = MoUpdateOrchestrator (cV = 6BW+6lnxVkC1GtQU.3.1), hr = 0x00000000
```

Basically everything I've found about that error for that update said it's because you're on an old edition of Windows 10, and updating to the latest would fix it, but 22H2 is the latest. I also tried an "in-place upgrade" with the Media Creation Tool, but once that finished and all of the other updates finished reinstalling, this one was still failing with the same error. I also tried a suggestion to manually install a different update, namely KB5015684, to resolve this, but it just told me that I already had the KB5015684 update installed.

What else can I try to do to resolve this? I don't really want to just ignore it, since every time I check for updates, Windows Update tries to download and install it again and so fails. I'm willing to do a full clean reinstall again, but since I just did one, I don't see why it would help.

Comment: Post the Windows Update log for diagnostic purposes. If you’re being told you already have the update then the update is already installed. KB5001716 was released last year in October. It’s been replaced several times since then by other servicing stack updates.

Comment: Any event KB5001716 is erroneously being installed, as it was released back in October, it most definitely was already installed. Just ignore it. **This absolutely is not a graphics display driver issue.**

Comment: This update appears to have been released, again, but only designed to provide you Windows 11 essentially. Details [here](https://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-quietly-installing-kb5001716-so-you-can-update-to-windows-11-or-newer-windows-10/), you can ignore the update if your system isn’t compatible with Windows 11

Comment: @Ramhound The update I already have installed isn't the same one that's failing. I edited the question to make that more clear. And even if I don't need this particular update, something definitely needs to be fixed, because Windows Update isn't supposed to try to install it and then fail every single time it runs. As for the log, I added what looks like the relevant part; it's way too long to add all of it.

Comment: Run the Windows Update Troubleshooter.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica - Let me restate this, Windows will not install the update, because it’s currently bug and you more than likely have it already installed as that also is common. It will install then attempt to install again which obviously cannot happen. Unless you cleared Windows Update I can almost guarantee the update that is failing will have already been installed. KB5015684 Is not applicable to your system since that’s an enablement patch to 22H2 from July 2022.

Comment: [Indeed, the fix to this problem, is to uninstall the update then allow windows update to reinstall it.](https://www.neowin.net/news/windows-10-kb5001716-install-fails-with-0x80070643-error-but-a-fix-seemingly-exists/) it’s unusual for Microsoft to reuse a patch number.

Comment: I suspect the reason this update is failing to update, even if you uninstall it, is due to the size of the WinRE partition.  Microsoft's recomendation to solve the WinRE partition size, is to run [PatchWinREScript_2004plus.ps1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5034957-updating-the-winre-partition-on-deployed-devices-to-address-security-vulnerabilities-in-cve-2024-20666-0190331b-1ca3-42d8-8a55-7fc406910c10), which will expand the partition to around 650MB.  It's actually closer to 625MB as the script should expand the size by 250MB.

Comment: @Ramhound Uninstalling the update and letting Windows Update reinstall it fixed it for me. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: This question is [being discussed on Meta](https://meta.superuser.com/q/15171/700114).